# SQL No of count month wise

Tags: sql, postgresql, count, feature-extraction

I have a data set as below,

[image]

data is basically year and month YYYYMM, I need to bring a count of months eg 202001 is appearing 3 times, hence the count should be Nov  3 ( Desired output is shared below )

[image]

I'm unable to start to bring out the desired output, help would be much appreciated.
(Temp tables are not allowed to be created in the servers)

Please find the link for sample data [link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3b95cfe7f47e0b3b2bad760f0e7ad785)

Help would be much appretiated.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql? (Many products have their own, non ANSI SQL compliant, date/time functions.)

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: @jarlh its Postgresql

Comment: Then you can remove the <mysql> tag.

Comment: @jarlh apologies, I just did, thank You!

Comment: I tried Select *, ```count(right(due_date_key,2)) AS count from T``` for some reason same is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `to_date()` to convert your number to a proper date, then group by that date:

```
select to_date(due_date_key::text, 'yyyymm') as due_date,
       count(*)
from t
group by due_date;
```

The "due_date" column is a proper date, you can use the `to_char()` function to format it differently:

```
select to_char(due_date, 'yyyy') as year,
       to_char(due_date, 'Mon') as output, 
       count
from (
  select to_date(due_date_key::text, 'yyyymm') as due_date,
         count(*) 
  from t
  group by due_date
) t
order by due_date;
```

[Online example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=1e51ced9b354d0a77fe266481ed2758b)